# How to run different VBA macros on selected work sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a workbook with different worksheets.

I am having macros for different worksheets.

I have a macro for all worksheets starting with `SOD`,
another macro for worksheets starting with `DMNE`, another macro for worksheets starting with `SAS`.
I have one macro for Usage tracking.

My requirement is when I click on the worksheet starting with `SOD`, how can I run the macro related to `SOD`. Similarly in all the sheets.

[image: WorkSheets]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may save a sub to your `ThisWorkbook` module. It will trigger on any worksheet activation event.
The worksheet can be passed on as an argument to the sub called.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Select Case Left(Sh.Name, IIf(InStr(Sh.Name, "-") > 0, InStr(Sh.Name, "-") - 1, Len(Sh.Name)))
    Case "SOD"
        Call SOD(Sh)
    Case "SAS"
        Call SAS(Sh)
    Case "DMNE"
        Call DMNE(Sh)
    Case "Usage Tracking"
        Call UsageTracking
    Case Else
        MsgBox "sheet procedure not defined"
End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on where you save your macros. Each recorded macro is saved in a module file. You have to open the Visual Basic Editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) and then you can define a sub routine on your sheet (Double-Click on `Worksheet1` to open a new editor window). There you can use something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
   If Left(ActiveSheet.Name, 3) = "SOD" then
      Call Module1.Macro1
      Call Module2.Macro2
   End If
End Sub
```